# Google Maps SDK for iOS multiple markers swift code

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, swift, marker

I want add multiple markers on the map when i Start the simulation i get the second marker.

I also get the following Output:

```
2015-04-29 11:25:10.184 xxxxx[2332:41372] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff3a9d83610 GMSMapView:0x7ff3a9d12b60.leading == UIView:0x7ff3a9d6dff0.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff3a9d83660 H:|-(0)-[GMSMapView:0x7ff3a9d12b60]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff3a9d6dff0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff3a9d83610 GMSMapView:0x7ff3a9d12b60.leading == UIView:0x7ff3a9d6dff0.leadingMargin>
```

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

///2
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //3
   locationManager.delegate = self
   locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()


    //Markers
    var marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(xx.xxxxxx, x.xxxxx )
    marker.title = "xxxx"
    marker.snippet = "xxxx"
    marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    marker.map = mapView

    var marker1 = GMSMarker()
    marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(xx.xxxxxx, x.xxxxx )
    marker1.title = "xxxx"
    marker1.snippet = "xxxx"
    marker1.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    marker1.map = mapView


}

// 1
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    // 2
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

        // 3
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        //4
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    }
}

}
```

Can anybody help me to get multiple markers with swift code

Thanks

Comment: Do you use autolayout in your project? The warning says there is problem with your autolayout constraints. Do you programmatically add the constraints or add them in your storyboard. You might need to remove the leading margin between your GMSMapView and UIView, you might provide screenshot of your storyboard.

Comment: thx Ztan. When i deleted the constraints i get now multiple markers..